# Definição na IDE phpstorm

Tags: ide, phpstorm

Uso a IDE phpstorm para programar eu já procurei e não consegui tirar tipo um traço que aparece no meu código que me faz confusão ao programar.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero tirar o traço que que aparece sempre em maior parte do código, quero tirar isso para o código aparecer limpo indicando erros quando os houver.

E possível ?

E queria também se alguém souber eu usei o tema Material através do seguinte site https://laravel-news.com/material-theme-for-phpstorm.

No site a imagem do tema as cores do código são diferentes ao que tenho na minha IDE depois de instalado o tema não ficou com as cores da imagem do site do tema.

Queria saber como posso por as cores como tem na imagem do site do tema que indiquei acima

Answer (score 2):

O que gera isso é a `Inspection` chamada `Typo`, porque suas variáveis estão em português.

Você pode desabilitar ou mudar as configurações dele dentro das opções do PHPStorm, em `Editor > Inspections > Spelling > Typo`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]